# CSS - simply modal, auto height on IE?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, modal-dialog

I have simply modal:

```
$('#report').click(function(e){
        $('#report_window').modal({
            autoResize: true
        });
        return false;
    });
```

And CSS:

```
#basic-modal-content {display:none;}

#simplemodal-overlay {
    background-color:#000;
}

#simplemodal-container {
    width: 600px;
    height: auto !important;
    top: 25% !important;
    color: #bbb;
    background-color: #fff;
    border: 4px solid #eee;
    padding: 12px;
    /* for IE */
    min-height:auto !important;
}

#simplemodal-container .simplemodal-data {padding:8px;}
#simplemodal-container a.modalCloseImg {background:url('../images/close.png') no-repeat; width:25px; height:29px; display:inline; z-index:3200; position:absolute; top:-15px; right:-16px; cursor:pointer;}

#simplemodal-container p {
    color: #333;
    font-size: 15px;
}

#simplemodal-container h3 {
    color: #6666cc;
    margin: 0px 0px 15px 0px;
}
```

For Opera, FF, Chrome its OK, but on IE modal height is always 100% :( margin of top its ok (always 25%), but height is to bottom...

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried declaring the position for the modal container?

```
position:absolute;
```

Comment: I add to modal-container:

position: absolute !important;
and dont work, but if i add:

position: fixed !important;
... its ok, but my modal window must be a fixed.

What now? :(